# Determining date or time Feature Class was created in File Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-database, file-geodatabase, time, feature-class

I had a script running at the office over the last 5 days and tried to remote on unsuccessfully since the 3rd day. I got here and it appears there was a power outage. Is there a way to find out the time a feature class was created? That would very much help me figure out how long the script took to run.

Comment: Would the date modified info in file explorer be sufficient?

Comment: If you open a File Geodatabase folder - the files listed are not the Feature classes in a File Geodatabase (as far as I know) but files that support the FGDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if I open the recent History .xml file,

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\History

The most recent will have parameters & env. settings & time. It gives all the geoprocessing tools used (if w/in arcpy) and all the settings and environment settings
and time started and finished.

Comment: But what about if it's something that was created years ago? Is there a non-hacky way to see the creation date/time of any feature class?