# Getting date modified for feature class within file geodatabase via ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, feature-class, metadata

For ordinary shapefiles located on a disk, I know I can check the date modified using os.stat (see [Creating table containing all filenames (and possibly metadata) in File Geodatabase?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34729/creating-table-containing-all-filenames-and-possibly-metadata-in-file-geodatab)), but how would I do so if I want to know the date modified for a feature class WITHIN a file geodatabase?

Specifically via ArcPy in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

There are some XML based methods ([Determining date or time Feature Class was created in File Geodatabase?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123397/determining-date-or-time-feature-class-was-created-in-file-geodatabase) and [How do I find out when a shapefile was created?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163892/how-do-i-find-out-when-a-shapefile-was-created)) but they seem a bit overkill just to get some basic metadata out.

Basic code:

```
import arcpy
gdbDir=r"D:\path\to\Default.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = gdbDir

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fclist:
    pass
    #code to extract feature class's date modified goes here
```

Comment: Probably also overkill as it tracks every feature, but have you considered Editor Tracking?  See [About tracking an editor's changes to data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m600000068000000)

Comment: See this old post on Geonet - [Date Modified / Created for feature class in file geodatabase?](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/46895) - it sounds like it may not be possible in arcpy unless it's been added in the last couple of releases (I doubt it has been).

Comment: @Midavalo That editor tracking looks interesting. I'll try going along that route for now, but for my use case, I only really need the last date modified since I'd like to know if I should overwrite the featureclass (if it was last updated a month ago).

Comment: I've looked into [arcpy.Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z00000018000000) for the [FeatureClass properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000001r000000) but no luck with a date modified property :/

Comment: I found a Python solution over at geonet but it looks like it will not work in a CITRIX environment https://geonet.esri.com/thread/74409.

Comment: @GBG which post on that thread contains your solution?

Comment: Micah Babinski's post...about half way down....