# How to get the "modified" date for a FeatureClass in a file geodatabase via ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, feature-class

There is a closed question which is similar to or identical to this question: [Getting date modified for a feature class within a file geodatabase via arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213042/getting-date-modified-for-a-feature-class-within-a-file-geodatabase-via-arcpy)

Looking at a file geodatabase featureclass in ArcCatalog, there is a **Modified** attribute showing the date that the featureclass was last changed:

[image]

This is not the same as the **Modified** date for its parent file geodatabase (which means that I can't obtain the featureclass 'modified' value via the operating system):

[image]

I'm limited to using the older ArcMap/ArcCatalog version of ArcPy, and I can't see where to find the 'modified on' date in the documentation, eg http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/featureclass-properties.htm

How can I access the Modified date via ArcPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with ArcPy. To access this property, you need to use ArcObjects.  You can do this from python via comtypes.

The following example is from [mbabinski1988 on Geonet](https://community.esri.com/thread/74409#comment-453427)

First set up comtypes and snippets.py:

- [Accessing ArcObjects from Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/accessing-arcobjects-from-python)
- [ArcObjects + comtypes at 10.1 and newer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37672/arcobjects-comtypes-at-10-1)

Then the following function can be used to return modified time:

```
def GetModifiedDate(gdb, tableName):    
    #  https://community.esri.com/thread/74409#comment-453427

    # Setup      
    GetStandaloneModules()      
    InitStandalone()      
    import comtypes.gen.esriSystem as esriSystem      
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase      
    import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesGDB as esriDataSourcesGDB      

    # Open the FGDB      
    pWS = Standalone_OpenFileGDB(gdb)    

    # Create empty Properties Set      
    pPropSet = NewObj(esriSystem.PropertySet, esriSystem.IPropertySet)      
    pPropSet.SetProperty("database", gdb)      

    # Cast the FGDB as IFeatureWorkspace      
    pFW = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)      

    # Open the table      
    pTab = pFW.OpenTable(tableName)      

    # Cast the table as a IDatasetFileStat      
    pDFS = CType(pTab, esriGeoDatabase.IDatasetFileStat)      

    # Get the date modified      
    return pDFS.StatTime(2)
```

Comment: Does another version of snippets.py exist for 10.3 and beyond?

Comment: @Nick Nope. For 10.3 I just changed line 20 from `keyESRI = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\ESRI\\Desktop10.2")` to `keyESRI = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\ESRI\\Desktop10.3")`.  Should work for >10.3 as well, just change to the appropriate version.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same (I think there may have been one additional instance in snippets.py I changed as well) but still got some errors ... I think something is wrong with how my registry because I also had to change HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to HKEY_USER_CURRENT